# Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.2.2 Nuget Update Fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, uwp

I'm trying to update the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform Nuget in my project but am unable to do so.  I'm currently on 5.1.0,  and I am attempting to update to 5.2.2.  The output when I attempt to update looks like this:

```
Restoring packages for 'MyApp'.
Restoring packages for C:\Users\Shayon\uwp\src\MyApp\project.json...
System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm-aot.
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64-aot.
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86-aot.
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
Package restore failed for 'MyApp'.
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyApp'.
========== Finished ==========
```

I'm not really sure how to interpret this error message.  Is it saying reflection is not supported on UWP?

I've tried clearing my nuget cache and restoring.  I have also tried uninstalling 5.1.0 and just installing straight to 5.2.2.  I'm using Nuget version 3.4.4 and VS 2015. I should also probably mention that I have been able to update the nuget for some other projects within the same solution without an issue.  In case it's relevant my Universal Windows Minimum version is `(10.0; Build 10240)` and my Target version is `(10.0; Build 10586)`

Any idea what is going awry here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Delete all references to other projects in the solution.
2. Uninstall all nuget packages *(remember which ones you had installed)*.
3. Add the nuget packages back, starting with the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` 5.2.2 package.
4. Do steps 1 through 3 for all projects in the solution
5. Add back all necessary project references for each project in the solution.

Following this procedure is what allowed me to update the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` package as well as all other packages that gave me the same error, like Automapper 4.2.1 to 5.0.2.

Comment: This worked for me but it's unfortunate this had to be done to update the framework.

Answer (score 2):

Updating to Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform : 5.2.2 is the right fix.  This package is required whenever dealing with packages that use netstandard.